# VIM: How do I reformat lists dependent on type of brackets using regex?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to write a crude code formatter in VIM using regex and it's generally going okay but I'm stuck on this one problem: How do I reformat a list only, and if only it's inside of certain type of brackets. Say for example I want to reformat

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

into

```
a = 
[1,
2,
3,
4]
```

but not do the operation on

```
b = |1, 2, 3, 4|
```

?

so far, I've used this which finds all occurrences of a word + a comma + any character and replaces it with a comma and a return.

```
au BufWrite <buffer> %s/\w\zs,\ze./,\r/ge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mix of `:s` and `substitute()` to work on the match. Considering the following text, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = |1, 2, 3, 4|
```

Using:

```
:%s/\s*\[.\{-}]/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\s\+', '\n', 'g')
```

Returns:

```
a =
[1,
2,
3,
4]
b = |1, 2, 3, 4|
```

What it does is to match the `[...]` and then replace every space inside it with a newline.

Comment: Wow, this is great. I was about to ask how you would go about making this sensitive to errors like no white space between items but I think I'll do that in a regex before calling this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the regex:

```
:%s/^.*|\n\zs\|,/,\r/g
```

Which mean `^.*|\n` that match every line that contains the character `|`, then the command `\zs` surpass this selection, now can match every comma from remaining lines...

Another more general way is:

```
:%s/^\(\(.*\[.*\)\@!.\)*$\n\zs\|,/,\r/g
```

which `^\(\(.*\[.*\)\@!.\)*$\n` mean to match every lines that not contains `[`.